# Multiplication of large numbers represented as arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

The numbers are stored in the arrays with their digits in reverse order. Here is a functions that should multiply two numbers, `lhs` and `rhs`, and store the product in `result`:

```
public static void MultiplyDigitArrays(int[] lhs, int[] rhs, int[] result)
{        
     int length1 = Math.Max(lhs.Length, rhs.Length);
     for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++)
     {
        int[] PartialProduct = new int[result.Length];

        int length2 = Math.Min(lhs.Length, rhs.Length);
        for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++)
        {
            int multiplicand = (lhs.Length < rhs.Length) ? rhs[i] : lhs[i];
            int multiplier = (lhs.Length < rhs.Length) ? lhs[j] : rhs[j];

            int product = PartialProduct[i + j] + multiplicand * multiplier;

            PartialProduct[i + j] = product % 10;
            int carry = product / 10;

            PartialProduct[i + j + 1] = PartialProduct[i + j + 1] + carry;
        }
        SumDigitArrays(PartialProduct, result, result);
    }
}
```

However, if I multiply:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] n1 = { 1, 1 };
    int[] n2 = { 1, 1 };
    int[] result = new int[Math.Max(n1.Length, n2.Length) * 2 + 1];

    MultiplyDigitArrays(n1, n2, result);

    PrintArray(result);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

the result is:

```
00132
```

instead of the expected:

```
00121
```

#### What am I doing wrong?

---

For the MCVE:

```
public static void PrintArray(int[] Array)
{
    int length = Array.Length;
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Console.Write(Array[i]);

    }
}

public static void SumDigitArrays(int[] a, int[] b, int[] result)
{
    int length = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int lhs = (i < a.Length) ? a[i] : 0;
        int rhs = (i < b.Length) ? b[i] : 0;

        int sum = result[i] + lhs + rhs;
        result[i] = sum % 10;

        int carry = sum / 10; 

        if (i + 1 < result.Length)
        {
            result[i + 1] = result[i + 1] + carry;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run it step-by-step in the debugger to see where the issue is?

Comment: @DStanley Yes, F10 /11 have been pushed many times and in the original code there are a lot of `WriteLines()` with current values of the local variables. After some time one needs another pair of eyes...

Comment: You have an `out of range exception` at `SumDigitArrays`  `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) result[i + 1] = result[i + 1] + carry;`

Comment: Apart from @WicherVisser 's answer, you may want to take a look at [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.100%29.aspx) unless you have a very specific need for this kind of implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because the third parameter use you in calling `SumDigitArrays` should be empty. Instead, you feed it the result variable which contains data on any iteration other than the first.

Implement your method like this:

```
    public static int[]  MultiplyDigitArrays(int[] lhs, int[] rhs)
    {
        int length1 = Math.Max(lhs.Length, rhs.Length);
        var result = new int[length1* length1];

        for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++)
        {
            int[] PartialProduct = new int[length1 * length1];

            int length2 = Math.Min(lhs.Length, rhs.Length);
            for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++)
            {
                int multiplicand = (lhs.Length < rhs.Length) ? rhs[i] : lhs[i];
                int multiplier = (lhs.Length < rhs.Length) ? lhs[j] : rhs[j];

                int product = PartialProduct[i + j] + multiplicand * multiplier;

                PartialProduct[i + j] = product % 10;
                int carry = product / 10;

                PartialProduct[i + j + 1] = PartialProduct[i + j + 1] + carry;
            }
            result = SumDigitArrays(PartialProduct, result);
        }

        return result;
    }


    public static int[] SumDigitArrays(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        int length = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
        var result = new int[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int lhs = (i < a.Length) ? a[i] : 0;
            int rhs = (i < b.Length) ? b[i] : 0;

            int sum = result[i] + lhs + rhs;
            result[i] = sum % 10;

            int carry = sum / 10;

            if (i + 1 < result.Length)
            {
                result[i + 1] = result[i + 1] + carry;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I was writing basically the same answer, +1

Comment: @eh I upvoted before the edit (just with the explanation). I'm not sure about the implementation, haven't tested, but passing an empty array worked for me ([this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ecr6lP) was where I was testing, my implementation was different, just as a test)

Comment: @eh let me know what doesn't work for you. (the edit concerned a typo in the text, not the code snippet.

Comment: @eh that said, WicherVisser 's implementation also seems to work fine: [check it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BDHHiA)

Comment: @Jcl yeah it works fine now; whatever I saw before did not... Should be noted that OP has to change his `Main` as well.

Comment: There was another error in the original code as remarked by Scott Chamberlain's in his answer. See the edit by Ziezi. His example 11 * 11 is not impacted by this, but you would notice it if you would use different values to test.

Comment: Yup, I just noted the error when trying different values, will +1 @ScottChamberlain 's answer below, which is *also* spot-on :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't exactly understand the logic you are performing, but

```
 int product = PartialProduct[i + j] + multiplicand * multiplier;
```

Gets evaluated as

```
int product = PartialProduct[i + j] + (multiplicand * multiplier);
```

Did you intend it to do

```
int product = (PartialProduct[i + j] + multiplicand) * multiplier;
```

As that could explain your error.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the two other answers given (which are spot-on and solve your problem), unless you have a very specific need, I'd recommend going for [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.100%29.aspx) if you need to multiply very large numbers.

For your specific needs (in case your numbers **must** come and go in an array of ints, which is a weird way to store any number), your `Multiply` could become:

```
public static void MultiplyDigitArrays(int[] lhs, int[] rhs, int[] result)
{        
    var n1 = BigInteger.Parse(string.Join("", lhs));
    var n2 = BigInteger.Parse(string.Join("", rhs));
    var resultBi = BigInteger.Multiply(n1, n2);     
    Array.Clear(result, 0, result.Length);
    var stResult = resultBi.ToString().PadLeft(result.Length, '0');
    for(int i = 0; i < stResult.Length; i++)
    {
        result[(stResult.Length-1)-i] = int.Parse(stResult[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Note that the burden of this function is actually converting your integer array back and forth, since an integer array is a weird format to store a number.

If you work directly with strings (or `BigInteger`s), this function would just not be necessary. For example, if working with strings containing the numbers, this could become:

```
public static string MultiplyBigNumbers(string lhs, string rhs)
{        
    var n1 = BigInteger.Parse(lhs);
    var n2 = BigInteger.Parse(rhs);
    return BigInteger.Multiply(n1, n2).ToString();      
}
```

And just call it: `MultiplyBigNumbers("3242", "42349");`

Then again, I'd recommend just working with `BigInteger` all the way down, and have it converted whenever you need to store it (for which a `byte` array makes more sense, and you can get it with `ToByteArray()`) or display (which can be easily done with a `ToString()` call)

Note that passing an array for the result is also pretty weird (for .NET anyway), since you don't need the original values. You'd be better off *returning* an array and calculating the needed length in the function itself, not having the caller figure it out.

Comment: Nice one! +1 Btw, maybe the OP ported his code from C/Matlab. Explains the odd technique.

Comment: @WicherVisser admiteddly, I've never used Matlab, but if it stores large integers as arrays of 0-9 integers, each representing a digit in base-10, I'd say  they are doing it wrong (and I doubt they are doing it wrong, being as famous as it is, but I've seen worse :-) )